# Move to character and drop into insert mode in VIM

Tags: vim

I recently fell in love with the `f`, `F`, `t`, and `T` commands in vim. Now I find myself frequently wanting to insert something at a position that can easily be navigated to with one of these commands, at least frequently enough that I would want to make the entire action "find character and insert text" repeatable via `.`. Currently, I can repeat the insert action, but I have to retype the find-character movement at every line where I want to repeat the insert.

Is there a command that combines the actions of these movement commands with the action of dropping into insert mode? Or, if not, is it possible to define such a command in my `.vimrc`?

Comment: Do you know about `;` (which repeats the last f/F/t/T command). With it, repeating becomes `;.`

Comment: @IngoKarkat No, I didn't. Thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: @cmaster the opposite direction of `;` is `,`, maybe you want to know too. if you have to insert many times in a line, consider `:s` or macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can repeat the last f/t/F/T motion via `;` (reverse via `,`), so you can repeat with two keys: `;.`

---

If that's not good enough, the *repeat.vim* plugin can be used to build a custom mapping that repeats just like the built-in commands:

```
"<Leader>it{char}       Insert text before the [count]'th occurrence of {char}
"                       to the right.
"<Leader>if{char}       Insert text after the [count]'th occurrence of {char}
"                       to the right.
"                       These mappings can be repeated atomically, this is
"                       faster than ";."
function! s:InsertAtCharPrepare( motion, moveOffMotion, repeatMapping )
    augroup InsertAtChar
        autocmd!
        " Enter insert mode automatically after the f/t motion.
        " XXX: :startinsert doesn't work on the first movement somehow, use
        " feedkeys() instead.
        autocmd CursorMoved <buffer> call feedkeys('a', 'n')

        " Prime repeat.vim after insertion is done.
        execute printf('autocmd InsertLeave <buffer> %scall repeat#set(%s, %d) | autocmd! InsertAtChar',
        \   (v:count1 <= 1 || empty(a:moveOffMotion) ? '' : 'execute "normal!" ' . string(a:moveOffMotion) . '|'),
        \   string(a:repeatMapping),
        \   v:count1
        \)

        " Abort in case something unexpected happens.
        autocmd WinLeave,BufLeave <buffer> autocmd! InsertAtChar
    augroup END

    return a:motion
endfunction
function! s:InsertAtCharRepeat( moveOffMotion, repeatMapping )
    let l:count = v:count1  " Save the original count to pass this on to repeat.vim.
    execute 'normal!' l:count . ';.' . (l:count <= 1 ? '' : a:moveOffMotion)
    call repeat#set(a:repeatMapping, l:count)
endfunction
" With "t" and [count] > 1, we need to move off from before {char} (where we're
" left when leaving insert mode) onto {char}, so that a repeat will happen
" before the next occurrence, not on the same again.
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(InsertUntilCharRepeat) :<C-u>call <SID>InsertAtCharRepeat('l', "\<lt>Plug>(InsertUntilCharRepeat)")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(InsertFromCharRepeat)  :<C-u>call <SID>InsertAtCharRepeat('', "\<lt>Plug>(InsertFromCharRepeat)")<CR>
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>it <SID>InsertAtCharPrepare('t', 'l', "\<lt>Plug>(InsertUntilCharRepeat)")
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>if <SID>InsertAtCharPrepare('f', '',  "\<lt>Plug>(InsertFromCharRepeat)")
```